# CMake: per configuration dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, dependencies

In CMake, is it possible to make target dependencies specific to a particular configuration?

My structure is an executable, which can be built with different backend renderers, one OpenGL and the other D3D. The backend renderers have their own (static) libraries, and only one library should be linked in, based on the configuration (eg. GL_Debug, D3D_Debug, etc). However, it doesn't seem as though the `add_dependency` command has any options for per-configuration settings.

My current solution is to use generation configurations (Debug, Release, etc), and an `option` to select the renderer type, and regenerate the solution if I'd like to switch. However, this is clunky if I want to switch between the two frequently. Ideally, I would have a solution with all the renderer configurations, and could just switch between them in Visual Studio.

Comment: `target_link_libraries` supports per-configuration settings. See documentation: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have been reading up on generator expressions and see how to do it now. Write into an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) command may link in configuration-dependent way. Alternatively, [generator-expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) can be used for [LINK_LIBRARIES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) property for executable/library.

Comment: Is there a big difference between the two? When should I use one over the other?

Comment: According to documentation, `target_link_libraries` actually set LINK_LIBRARIES property to generator-expression, depended from configuration. If it is not sufficient for you, you can set `LINK_LIBRARIES` propert directly.