# CMake - separating project configurations from target configurations

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I have an executable, which supports two rendering backends (GL and D3D), each implemented in a separate static library. I have project configurations permuted on the debug-level (eg. Debug, Release, etc), and the renderer, so the final configurations are (Debug_GL, Debug_D3D, etc.). In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810049/cmake-per-configuration-dependencies?noredirect=1#comment51561779_31810049), I learned how to make per-configuration dependencies.

My problem now is that I also have additional static libraries, which are not dependent on the renderer type. When I create the (CMake) project configurations above by setting  `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`, these static library projects also get configurations permuted by the renderer type. I do not want this, because those configurations have separate object/library directories, etc., but they are essentially duplicates.

My main focus is generating for Visual Studio, so ideally the generated solution along with the renderer backend libraries would have the full set of permutations, whereas the non-renderer specific libraries would only have the 'debug-level' configurations. Is this somehow possible with CMake?

Comment: Are these additional static libraries built in the same project?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration set is *global* for whole project. Each configuration is built in its own directory. E.g., from the description of [LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) property:

> This property specifies the directory into which library target files should be built. Multi-configuration generators (VS, Xcode) append a per-configuration subdirectory to the specified directory.

In other words, **any target** (e.g., library) **built within project cannot be shared between different configurations**.

If you want some targets have their own configuration set, you should move them into another project. Disadvantage of this approach is that it is difficult to make one project being automatically rebuilt while sources for another project are changed.

Comment: Going with the two project approach, I would have the one project use `include_external_msproject` to include the second project's libraries into one solution?

Comment: I am not sure how using `include_external_msproject` correlate with configurations. In my answer I imply using `find_project` or `ExternalProject_add`.